# Is there a way to use android studio just to maintain and update drawables on an existing APK?

Tags: android, android-studio, dex, apktool

I would like to update a particular abandoned app with newer good quality drawables without actually changing the codebase of the app - just the resources.
My goal is to replace most of the .pngs with vector drawables so the scaling looks great.

While we do have apktool and disassemblers, I don't really have the need for that as I won't be changing any java code.

I would like a way in which Android studio recognizes the classes.dex file kind of like an external library and I can directly work on replacing the resources without worrying about downloading any java dependencies.

After updating the drawables, the end result would be bundling the new files + classes.dex to generate an updated APK.

Comment: `apktool` has an option to disable source code decompilation (decompile resources only).

Comment: Yes, however, I need a way to import them to the android studio like a normal app (except the java part is read-only classes.dex). So I can focus on editing the resources through android studio. Ex- Rearranging custom layouts , icons etc.
I can't manually add them in a fresh project as there are proprietary dependencies bundled in the APK, so if the APK could be loaded like a jar library, Astudio can still recognize the XMLs.

Comment: AndroidStudio is not designed to work this way. You can try to open the APK file in Jadx and export it to a gradle project just to have something AS can open. Then you could edit the resources in AS, but re-integration would need an `apktool` decompile manually integrate and rebuild.

Comment: just to replace resources such as .png files in drawables folder you can use winrar or 7z program to extract and replaces files you have changed. To modify .xml layout files to change UI you HAVE TO decompile .apk first (only resources.arsc if you need), modify all .xml files you need and then compile resources back to resources.arsc file. With such approach you can not use any of existing program to natively support your resources management operation.

Comment: I feared as much, ill have to stick to manually editing them after decompiling. thanks everyone